# Индекс (отсчитываемый от нуля) должен быть больше или равен нулю, но меньше размера списка аргументов

Tags: c#, циклы

```
class Program
{
    static int div(int n, int n1, int sz)
    {
        int obj = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < sz; i++)//вроде здесь ругается
        {
            if (n % i == 0 && n1 % i == 0)
            {
                obj = n / n1;
            }

        }
        int s = n / obj;
        int s1 = n1 / obj;

        if (s1==0 || s1==1)

        {
            return s;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("{0}/{1}", s, s1);

        return 1;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Введите a: ");
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Введите b: ");
        int n1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Введите диапозон: ");
        int sz = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Дробь {0}/{1} = ", div(n, n1, sz));


    }
}
```

Вот мой код,не знаю,почему ругается :(

Comment: @0xdb вы издеваетесь? Там же деление на i следующей строчкой.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в строке

```
Console.WriteLine("Дробь {0}/{1} = ", div(n, n1, sz));
```

В формате ожидается два параметра: `{0}`, `{1}`

Передан же, только один `div(n, n1, sz)`

Comment: Ааа точно,спасибо)